# RELOCATION ERROR - GLIBC symbol not defined; Manjaro Linux

Tags: asp.net-core, glibc, manjaro, relocation

im a beginner when it comes to Linux trying to run an ASP.Net Core 6 webapp build, but launching it only gives the following error:
`relocation error: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_fatal_printf version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference`

I found a few threads talking about similar issues but none seem to give me a proper idea of what I should do to fix this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)